# HTML5 audio event 'progress' not firing

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, events, audio-streaming

I am building an a/v html5 streaming web app.  This question pretains to the audio portion of the project, but i'm sure i will run into a similar situation when i get started on the video portion.  My target device is the iPad's safari browser (hence why i have to do this html5).  Playback works fine, but i have a loading bar which needs to reflect how much of the track has been loaded.  Following the w3 spec, i tried to implement this the following way using jQuery:

```
var that = this;
that.player = $('audio')[0];

$('that.player').bind('progress',function(){
    var buffer = that.player.buffered.end(0)      
    that.updateLoadBuffer(buffer);
});
```

This did not work.  'that.player.buffered' returns a TimeRanges object, and TimeRanges have a method 'end(index)' which returns the playback position of end of the buffer in seconds for the TimeRange specified by 'index.'  TimeRanges also have a .length property which tells you how many TimeRanges are encapsulated by the object.  When i tried to log that property i found that TimeRanges.length = 0, meaning no TimeRanges are passed back.  Also when i threw logging statements into the bound function, i found that the 'progress' event was never fired.  I have separate functions for the 'loadedmetata' and 'timeupdate' events which follow a similar format, and those fire off as expected.  I tried other methods for capturing events to no avail:

```
that.player.onprogress = function(e){
     console.log('progressEvent heard');
};

that.player.addEventListener('progress',progressHandler, false)
function progressHandler(e){
    console.log('progressEvent heard');
};
```

Neither of these triggered my console message.  My audio tag declaration is as follows:

```
<audio style="width:0;height:0;"></audio>
```

what am i doing wrong here?

UPDATE:  I am using wowzamediaserver to handle the http streaming.  I dont know if that could have anything to do with it.

YET ANOTHER UPDATE:  I realize i do not have a source in my audio tag, that is because i set it dynamically using jquery, as follows:

```
$('audio').attr('src','http://my.wowza.server:1935/myStreamingApp/_definst_/mp3:path/to/my/track/audio.mp3/playlist.m3u8');
```

again i am not having playback issues so this shouldn't have any bearing on my problem, but i just want to give you guys as clear of a picture as possible.

Comment: I'm having the same problem almost 2 years later - I believe it's due to using playlist.m3u8, but have yet to find a way around it.  Any luck yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 specification is still a draft under development so browsers that support it are essentially conforming to a yet-to-be-finalized spec.  As such I wouldn't expect their HTML5 features to be fully functional...

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what the current implementation landscape looks like for the `progress` event, but when I was working on an HTML5 audio player several months ago I remember that I just couldn't get it to fire in Safari or Chrome. I ended up using a timer instead. Probably nothing you couldn't figure out, but here's a simplified version:

The Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    audio = $('body').find("audio").get(0);
});

function play() {
    audio.play();
    int = window.setInterval(updateProgress, 30);
}

function pause() {
    audio.pause();
    window.clearInterval(int);
}

function updateProgress() {
    progress_seconds = Math.ceil(audio.currentTime);
    progress_percent = Math.ceil(audio.currentTime / audio.duration * 100);
    $('#progress_seconds').html('Seconds: ' + progress_seconds);
    $('#progress_percent').html('Percent: ' + progress_percent);
};
```

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="so.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<audio>
    <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<a id="play" href="#" onclick="play();">Play</a>
<a id="pause" href="#" onclick="pause();">Pause</a>

<span id="progress_seconds">_</span>
<span id="progress_percent">_</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Progress events won't work in many use cases as of iOS 8.1.  According to Apple's documentation:

> Note: On the iPad, Safari does not begin downloading until the user clicks the poster or placeholder. Currently, downloads begun in this manner do not emit progress events.

I can corroborate that javascript triggered playback will not fire progress events. I have not tested using the HTML5 audio native controls `<audio controls></audio`.

Ref:
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html