# jQuery preloader for individual audio elements on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a single page application that has multiple audio files being loaded into the document. I've created a preloader spinner with a class called '.spinner'. How would I go about showing this preloader spinner for each individual audio element until they are done loading?

Answer (score 0):

according to **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)** and **[this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadstart.asp)** the following events occur during the loading process, in this order:

1. **loadstart** - Sent when loading of the media begins.
2. **durationchange** - The metadata has loaded or changed, indicating a change in duration of the media.  This is sent, for example, when the media has loaded enough that the duration is known.
3. **loadedmetadata** - The media's metadata has finished loading; all attributes now contain as much useful information as they're going to.
4. **loadeddata** - The first frame of the media has finished loading.
5. **progress** - Sent periodically to inform interested parties of progress downloading the media. Information about the current amount of the media that has been downloaded is available in the media element's buffered attribute.
6. **canplay** - Sent when enough data is available that the media can be played, at least for a couple of frames.
7. **canplaythrough** - Sent when the ready state changes to CAN_PLAY_THROUGH, indicating that the entire media can be played without interruption, assuming the download rate remains at least at the current level. Note: Manually setting the currentTime will eventually fire a canplaythrough event in firefox. Other browsers might not fire this event.

So looking at those events you can play around with 2 of them: `loadstart` and `progress`. Or instead you can use `duration` and `currentTime` properties of audio element like **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7113226/1869773)**.