# Find buffered percentage of video element

Tags: javascript, html

I need to find buffered percentage of a video from `<video>` element.

I was trying to find this using the below code,

```
videoElement.addEventListener("progress", bufferHandler);
var bufferHandler = function(e) {
    var buffered = e.target.buffered.end(0);
    var duration = e.target.duration;
    var buffered_percentage = (buffered / duration) * 100;
    console.log(buffered_percentage);
}
```

But the value is not correct,If I play the complete video `buffered_percentage` not resulting at 100%.

```js
var videoElement = document.getElementById("myVideo");
videoElement.addEventListener("progress", bufferHandler);
var bufferHandler = function(e) {
  var buffered = e.target.buffered.end(0);
  var duration = e.target.duration;
  var buffered_percentage = (buffered / duration) * 100;
  console.log(buffered_percentage);
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: I am not able to see anything in the console. Are you sure the event is triggering?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I am also wondering ,There is nothing in the console while it buffered

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111978/html5-audio-event-progress-not-firing) may help you. And this question seems like a dupe of that.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy But i am using latest chromium build Version 49.0.2623.108 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) .I think it is something wrong in my code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Media Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) : `progress`

> Sent periodically to inform interested parties of progress downloading
>   the media. Information about the current amount of the media that has
>   been downloaded is available in the media element's buffered
>   attribute.

Code posted by OP :

```
    <script>
var videoElement = document.getElementById("myVideo");
videoElement.addEventListener("progress", bufferHandler);
var bufferHandler = function(e) 
{
  var buffered = e.target.buffered.end(0);
  var duration = e.target.duration;
  var buffered_percentage = (buffered / duration) * 100;
  console.log(buffered_percentage);
}
    </script>
```

Output Console :

[image]

If you could please add `script` as below ,it would be great :

```
    <script>

var videoElement = document.getElementById("myVideo");
videoElement.addEventListener("progress", bufferHandler);
function bufferHandler(e)
 {
if (videoElement && videoElement.buffered && videoElement.buffered.length > 0 && videoElement.buffered.end && videoElement.duration)
 {

  var buffered = e.target.buffered.end(0);
  var duration = e.target.duration;
  var buffered_percentage = (buffered / duration) * 100;
  console.log(buffered_percentage);
  }
}


    </script>
```

Output Console : **51.699%**

[image]

**Video Buffering 100% :**

[image]

**Tested on :**

[image]

Note : Have used another video with some length and size for testing rather that was posted by OP.

Thanks

```js
var videoElement = document.getElementById("myVideo");
videoElement.addEventListener("progress", bufferHandler);
function bufferHandler(e)
 {
if (videoElement && videoElement.buffered && videoElement.buffered.length > 0 && videoElement.buffered.end && videoElement.duration)
 {
  
  var buffered = e.target.buffered.end(0);
  var duration = e.target.duration;
  var buffered_percentage = (buffered / duration) * 100;
  console.log(buffered_percentage);
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://client.99nfomatics.in/test/files/B.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  
</video>
```